# Why isn't the --browser-test flag included in Puppeteer's default list of Chromium flags?

Tags: chromium, puppeteer

I'm just curious if there's any known unwanted effect of this flag on automation, or if it can make my tests less valid.

I'm currently running tests with this flag and it doesn't seem to hurt anything. Is it just overlooked?

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#browser-test
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/lib/Launcher.js#L38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--browser-test` activates an internal test used by the Chromium developers regarding canvas repaints.

Some [older code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/32352ad08ee673a4d43e8593ce988b224f6482d3/content/shell/common/shell_switches.cc) in the repository, gives this hint

> Tells Content Shell that it's running as a content_browsertest.

And [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=685796) in the Chromium repository contains more information:

> We need a test that checks canvas capture happens for N times when there are N repaints. This test is not appropriate for webkit layout tests as it is slow and there are mock streams involved.

Looks like they added a special flag for this test.

Therefore, **you should not activate this flag** as this test is about internal browser tests by the developer team not about testing websites.